# List all artifact types for a project in Doors Next

Tags: python, ibm-doors

I am trying to list all attributes for a given project, however i got stuck with this error JSONDecoderError: Expecting Value
Here is my code, any HELP would be appreciated.

```
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

# Set up connection parameters
base_url = 'https://example.com/rm/'

auth_url = base_url + 'example/example'

headers = { 'OSLC-Core-Version': '2.0', 'Accept': 'application/rdf+xml' }

response = requests.post(auth_url, headers=headers, verify=False) 
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(f"Response status code: {response.status_code}")

if response.status_code == 200: 
   print("Successfully authenticated to DOORS Next!") 
   project_info = response.json()
   attributes = project_info.get('oslc_rm:attributes', [])
    
    # Print the attributes
   for attribute in attributes:
        print(attribute.get('dc:title'))
else:
    print("Failed to authenticate to DOORS Next. Status code: " + str(response.status_code)) 
    print("Error: Failed to get project attributes")
```

**Response:**
*Response status code: 200
Successfully authenticated to DOORS Next!*

Comment: response is not valid Json, Should check the content type to make sure it's json. It's not, as you specify in the header that it's `rdf+xml`

Comment: i am expecting the response to be in XML. I tried with application/xml and application/json but still same response. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

The content you are getting is in one of the RDF (Resource Description Framework) formats. RDF is used to represent graph data in a standard way. You can't use JSON libraries to parse it (not even JSON-LD!) because JSON is only capable of representing trees out of the box.

You should consider using https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ in your case.

See https://docs.oasis-open-projects.org/oslc-op/core/v3.0/oslc-core.html for more details about the protocol.